# Como escrever uma função que retorne valores adequados de uma data (dia, mes e ano), a fim de que esses sejam atribuídos a variáveis do tipo struct?

Tags: c, funções, struct

Eu queria desenvolver uma função responsável por analisar o formato da data inserida, entretanto os valores adequados teriam que ser retornados para uma outra função responsável pelo cadastro de outros elementos. Este é o momento em que eu chamo na função `cadastro` a função de `verificarFormatoData.`

```
printf ("Informe o dia o mes e o ano\n");
scanf ("%d/%d/%d", &inserir.dia, &inserir.mes, &inserir.ano);
verificarFormatoData (inserir.dia, inserir.mes, inserir.ano)
```

Os valores corretos de `verificarFormatoData` deveriam ser igualados ao `inserir.dia; inserir.mes; inserir.ano.` Segue abaixo a forma em que ela foi escrita.

```
int verificarFormatoData (int dia, int mes, int ano){
    while (formatoData(dia, mes, ano)==0){
        printf ("A data inserida e invalida, por favor digite uma data existente"); 
        scanf ("%d/%d/%d", &dia, &mes, &ano);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Quando acabar o while os valores serão zero, então não vou conseguir recuperá-los para utilizá-los na função cadastro para que sejam escritos em um arquivo. Segue abaixo a função `formatoData` que gera o loop em `verificarFormatoData`

```
int formatoData (int dia, int mes, int ano){
    if (dia<0 || dia>31){
        printf ("\nERRO:Informe um dia válido\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (mes<=0 || mes>12){
        printf ("\nERRO:Informe um mes valido\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (ano<2010){
        printf ("\nERRO:Informe um ano acima de 2010\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Se vc já criou um `struct` para a data, por que não usá-lo diretamente em vez de passar dia, mês e ano separadamente? Não entendi exatamente o que vc quer fazer, mas enfim, uma sugestão: https://ideone.com/xJB7ew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Darlam Alves**  ,  no while os valores não se perdem , não ,  e o que acontece nesse seu código é que você colocou caracteres especiais entres os especificadores de tipo no scanf , e isso causa erros na leitura , assim da função retornam valores aleatórios , e também seria melhor usar string's para a leitura , pois assim se for digitados caractres que não sejam dígitos não haverá perda de controle do programa , e se você precisar usar valores inteiro , então converta as string's "array" para int com a função atoi , e seu código com algumas modificações poderia ser assim  :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
    char s_dia[10];
    char s_mes[10];
    char s_ano[10];
    int  dia;
    int  mes;
    int  ano;
}data;
int formatoData ( int , int , int );
int verificarFormatoData ( data* , char* , char* , char* );
int main()
{
    data inserir;
    inserir.dia = 11;
    printf("Informe o dia o mes e o ano\n");
    scanf ("%s%s%s", inserir.s_dia , inserir.s_mes ,     /// nao pode colocar caracteres
                                     inserir.s_ano);     /// estranhos no scanf , nao !
    verificarFormatoData (&inserir, inserir.s_dia, inserir.s_mes, inserir.s_ano  );
    printf("\n\tDatas Corretas !  >>>  ");                    /// Quando retorna é porque estao certas
    printf("%d / %d / %d",inserir.dia,inserir.mes,inserir.ano);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    return 0;
}
int verificarFormatoData ( data* inserir , char diA[10], char meS[10], char anO[10] )
{
    int dia = atoi(diA);                                 /// se houver carac q nao seja digitos
    int mes = atoi(meS);                                 /// atoi retorna zero para a variaveL
    int ano = atoi(anO);                                 /// converter array "string" para inteiro
    while (   formatoData (  dia , mes , ano  )  ==  0 ) /// se zero entao tem erros
    {                                                    /// escrever o resultaDo para saber como estah
        printf("\n\t==  valores ReceBides  ==\n\
                \r\tDia -> %d \n\
                \r\tMes -> %d \n\
                \r\tAno -> %d\n",
                dia, mes,   ano);                        /// apenas uma chamada a printf
                                                         /// fica mais rapido a execucao
        printf ("A data inserida eh invalida .\n\
                \rpor favor digite uma data existente -: ");
        scanf ("%s%s%s", diA , meS , anO );              /// caract estranhos no scanf
                                                         /// causam falhas inesperadas
        dia = atoi(diA);                                 /// se houver carac q nao seja digitos
        mes = atoi(meS);                                 /// atoi retorna zero para a variaveL
        ano = atoi(anO);                                 /// converte string em int
    }
    inserir->dia = dia;                                  /// essa setinha serve parac acessar campos de struct
    inserir->mes = mes;                                  /// coloco três barras pois uso o codeblocks e a cor
    inserir->ano = ano;                                  /// nos comentarios ficam mais visiveis assim
    ///  essa linha de baixo nao é necessaria , pois ela é uma repeticao
    ///  de  inserir->dia = dia;
    (*inserir).dia = dia;                                /// usando um cast também daria certo
                                                         /// aqui só para referencia
/// return inserir;                                      /// se quiser pode deletar essa linha aqui de cima
    return 0;                                            /// se Quiser pode retornar esse vetor de struct "inserir"
}                                                        /// mas nao faria difereça pois essa struct é variáveL Global

int formatoData ( int dia, int mes, int ano )
{
    int tem_erro = 0;
    if ( dia < 1 || dia > 31 )
    {
        printf ("\nERRO:Informe um dia válido\n\n");
        tem_erro++;
    }
    if ( mes < 1 || mes > 12 )
    {
        printf ("\nERRO:Informe um mes valido\n\n");
        tem_erro++;
   }
   if  ( ano < 2010 )
    { 
        printf ("\nERRO:Informe um ano acima de 2010\n\n");
       tem_erro++;
   } 
    if(  tem_erro )return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: É claro que pode ter caracteres "especiais" no `scanf`, pode ter qualquer caractere - desde que, é claro, o usuário digite corretamente, por isso é importante verificar o retorno dele: https://ideone.com/L0ZCBD